# jquery display all divs between given divs

Tags: jquery, html

First of all this is my markup:

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

What I want to do is when I click on a div with the class **first**, I want to display all the next divs with a class **second** till the next **first** class.

Is there a way to to this with jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".first").click(function () {
            $(this).nextUntil(".first").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

No you dont have to.

```
$(".first").nextUntil(".first").show()
```

Here is detailed info about it:

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Answer (score 1):

Example fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nVP7P/5/

```
$(".first").click( function () {
     $(".second").css("display","none");
    var next = $(this).next();
   while (next.hasClass("second"))
 {
    next.css("display", "inline");
    next = next.next();
 }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
$( '.first' ).click(function(){
    var foundFirst = false;
    var next = $(this);
    while( !foundFirst ){
        next = next.next();
        if(next.hasClass( 'first' )){
            foundFirst = true;
        } else {
            next.show();
        }
    }
});
```